Need help with film about people fighting/racing for survival
I am looking for a film title but I only remember bits of it.
The film was American (I think) but I don't think it was filmed in America (possibly somewhere like Japan or China)
I don't know how old the film is but I watched it in mid to late 80s. The film was in colour.
I remember it being a sort of ninja/martial arts film.
Main plot: some people (I think they're people that have broken the law) are entered into a stamina kind of race/game. They are in some kind of forest/jungle and they have to escape the ninjas that are chasing them. (I remember that the ninjas couldn't talk as their tongues had been cut out) I can't remember if the 'contestants' have to fight each other or not.
I seem to remember the film being based in ancient China but I might be wrong.

Could it be The running man with Schwarzenegger and Richard Dawson?

Nope.. nothing like that. It has ninjas in it and the race is outside.. like a forest or jungle or something like that. Ty for answering though :)

Could it be Surviving the Game, with Rutger Hauer and Ice T? It has nothing to do with China, but everything else fits... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlUQFDxJedg

Not it either, i have seen that though, not a bad film :)

Could this be what your looking for?! 



Omg... thats it. Ty sooooo much. (It looks really cheesy now lol but i watched this so many times when i was younger)
